# I am having trouble getting data returned from a post request in angular/typscript frontnend and asp.net backend

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript, http-post

I have a web application I am developing that depends on back end processing. I am sending a post request from my Angular(v14)/Typescript front end to an ASP.NET back end.

Back end code

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> ProcessExcelFile(IFormFile fileData, IFormCollection data)
{
      string guid = await processor.ProcessFile(fileData, data) //Imp not important for question.
    
      return guid;
}
```

Front end code

```
var guid: string = "";
this.http.post<string>('/api', formData).subscribe(result => {guid = result;});
```

I have confirmed the backend is being hit correctly through debugging and returns the correct data.

But the front end "guid" is empty after I call the post request. What I am doing wrong here?

The back end processing could take a few seconds, is that the problem? What can I do about this?

Comment: Check your network logs in your browser and make sure that it is posting successfully and see what is being returned. It looks like "Guid" could either be returning null or the POST request is failing and the guid is never being set to begin with.

Comment: @kasprdev When I attach a debugger to the backend, I see that the front end does end up hitting my back end code and the guid has a value before it's returned. I will play with the browser logs and see if anything jumps out at me though, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it's a JSON response you should be able to do it like this:

// Backend response

```json
{
  "guid": "randomId123",
}
```

```
let guid: string;
this.http.post<any>('/api', formData).subscribe(result => {
    guid = result.guid;
});
```

If it's not JSON Response, could please share how the response look alike?

**Update in case the response is just text:**

```
let guid: string;
this.http.post<string>('/api', formData,{ responseType:'text'}).subscribe(result => {
    guid = result;
});
```

Comment: A string or number is valid JSON so simply returning `"guid"` or `123` would be a valid JSON format.

Comment: Ah thank you for sharing that information with me! I was not aware of that.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this change did not work, but thanks for trying. I am not sure what the response type is when you just return a basic string from the controller. I am looking into this and trying to examine one of my backend responses.

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe that will help to deal with it. You can check the response information in the browser dev tools when making the request.

Comment: Looking at the browser dev tools, it is expecting a plain text response. What is more interesting is the request has no response and is apparently still ongoing... this must be why I am not getting the guid back. It's stuck somewhere. Looking into this...

Answer (score 0):

Just by going through the code snippets, not returning an IActionResult stands out to me so you could give this is a shot and check if it solves the issue

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessExcelFile(IFormFile fileData, IFormCollection data)
{
  string guid = await 
  processor.ProcessFile(fileData, data) //Imp not important for question.

  return ok(guid);
}
```

This basically sends an OK API response with the guid as the content

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the post request would not finalize until the function it lived in that started from a button click on the web page finished.

Instead of creating the guid variable in the same function as the post request, I changed it to a global variable. I am now getting the correct data in the guid variable but only after the button press function finishes.

```
this.http.post<string>('/api', formData).subscribe(result => {this.guid = result;});
```